# Apache: Unable to setup simple SVN users and access rights

Tags: apache, svn

I have a SVN repository stored on an Apache server.

Authentification was done through SSPI, and I'm trying to move this to more basic stuff (having a local list of user/password).

My **httpd.conf**:

```
LoadModule sspi_auth_module modules/mod_auth_sspi.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so

... 

<Location /svn_toto>

  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath D:\web_server\svn_repositories_test
  AuthzSVNAccessFile D:\web_server\svn_repositories_test\svnaccessfile.txt
  #Satisfy Any
  Require valid-user
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository toto"
  AuthUserFile D:\web_server\svn_repositories_test\users.txt

  SVNIndexXSLT "/svnindex.xsl"

</Location>
```

My **users.txt**:

```
[users]
super = super
jean = jean
```

My **svnaccessfile.txt**:

```
[groups]
admin = super

[/]
@admin = rw

[cloisonnement:/]
jean = rw
super = rw

[cloisonnement:/trunk]
jean = rw
super = rw
```

Now, from a client machine, I try:

```
svn ls https://servername/svn_toto/cloisonnement/trunk --username super --password super
```

And this fails and asks me password:

```
Authentication realm: <https://servername:443> Subversion Repository toto
Username: super
Password for 'super': *****
Authentication realm: <https://servername:443> Subversion Repository toto
Username: super
Password for 'super': *****
svn: E215004: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://servername/svn_toto/cloisonnement/trunk'
svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing svn build-in clear-text authentication and basic http authentication in apache:

by stating

```
  Require valid-user
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile D:\web_server\svn_repositories_test\users.txt
```

You pointing **Apache http** server to organize the authentication.
To add a user to the file you need to perform:

```
htpasswd D:\web_server\svn_repositories_test\users.txt super
htpasswd D:\web_server\svn_repositories_test\users.txt jean
```

The programm will prompt you for the respective passwords and stores them encrypted in the users.txt file.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I totally missed that subtility. I'm definitely not a server admin, was just trying to rework the way our repository access rights are managed....